# Не выходит правильно подключить glew32

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, dll, visual-studio-2015

Решил начать изучать OpenGL. IDE - MVS 15
Скачал glew и glfw.
По уроку на [ютубе](https://youtu.be/YPssCmB_a-Y) подключил их.
При запуске приложения пишет, что `glew32.dll отсутствует`. В настройках указал, что приложение 32-битное, моя ОС 64-битная (насколько я знаю, проблем с этим быть не должно).
Раз уж mvs не видит `glew32.dll` в папке, которую я указал, закинул его в папку System32. Ничего не поменялось. После этого закинул в папку SysWOW64.
Теперь у меня другая ошибка: `ошибка при запуске приложения (0xc000007b)`. Погуглил эту ошибку, но проку это не добавило
Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: А может быть легче скомпилить все это вместе с исходниками? Ну не динамическую библиотеку подключать, а статическую

Comment: @Alexander то есть glew и glfw закинуть в папку с проектом?

Comment: Нет, прочитайте про статическую и динамическую линковку

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто

Вот нужные вам файлы

Скомпилированые библиотеки
https://www.youtube.com/redirect?redir_token=ed2T28exY2LRkv8TlxuAYbhSsIl8MTUyMjMwNDU2OUAxNTIyMjE4MTY5&q=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fopen%3Fid%3D1h3a95vG3LbCKUtAk26vvcfQqFFPo_U9-&event=video_description&v=nZteX9rIhD0

Проект для проверки
https://www.youtube.com/redirect?redir_token=ed2T28exY2LRkv8TlxuAYbhSsIl8MTUyMjMwNDU2OUAxNTIyMjE4MTY5&q=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%2Fd%2F1Ec33mC5ET-fYbcSERu4Q6wGi6jylAuq_%2Fview%3Fusp%3Dsharing&event=video_description&v=nZteX9rIhD0

dll файлы бросаеш к скомпилированой програмке и и в папку с с именем проекта (для проверки напишы алгоритм записи ф файл и там где после запуска програмы из вызуалки прикомпиляцыи, Где файл появиться туда dll ки тожэ скопируй)

вот в этом https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5xaleGw58Y уроке есть такая проблема и там показано как исправить (только урок на украинском). просто пролистай к первой компиляцыи и уввидеш ошыбку и ришение. пи етой проблеме версия визуалки неважна.